# Breakdown `composer update` to avoid php memory limit

Tags: magento2

Sounds not possible, but I will ask anyway.

When being in shared hosting, I am stuck on php memory limit exception on `composer update`.

**Is there a way to breakdown update to smaller parts?**

I am upgrading from 2.2.4 to 2.3. System requires `1035M`.

My shared hosting doesn't let me increase `php memory limit`. It is set to max at `768M`.

*Editing for one more bump to top*

Comment: As far as I know, Magento doesn't recommend using the shared hosting.

Comment: Yeah, but this is the problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but you can still try, override the **`php memory limit settings`** of a shared hosting by creating a **`.htaccess`** file and add:

**`php_value memory_limit 1048M`**

Comment: It doesn't help. It still exhausts. Shared hosting has cap of 768M. I was looking to upgrade partially so that it doesn't require higher memory.

Comment: sorry for that. anyway, there could be a way for that but sure it would take more setup configuration. the easiest solution would be, upgrading from local then uploading it after on your shared host. just an idea